# Passing parameterized sql query as parameter to a stored procedure not working

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to pass a parametrized SQL query as a parameter to a stored procedure in SQL Server but can't get it to work. This is what I've tried

Stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SroredProc]
   @Qry nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   EXEC sp_executesql @Qry;
End
```

C# code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycon"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
string s = "select id,name from tbl where id=@id";
con.Open();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = s;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1);
cmd= new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "SroredProc";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qry", s);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: Seems like a really bad idea. What *benefit* do you see from passing a **parametrized query** to a stored procedure? If it's already properly parametrized - just execute it!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should something like below. Again, there is no point opening the connection so early; rather open it just before calling/executing the command.

```
int id = 1;
SqlConnection con = new 
SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycon"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
string s = string.format("select id,name from tbl where id={0}",id);
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "SroredProc";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qry", s);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: on supplying every value needed here I'm getting StoredProc has too many arguments specified

Comment: @user3472352, not sure I understood but per your post storedproc accepts only one parameter which you passing in code. is there any thing else you missed to mention in your post?

Comment: No I've written everything what is needed

Comment: I want it to be safe from the sql injections that's why need to make it parameterized so your solution        string s = string.format("select id,name from tbl where id={0}",id);       doesn't sound good

Answer (score 0):

There are two things:

You are forgetting to associate the connection to the command

```
cmd.Connection = con;
```

I would change the declaration of your string s to, your @Qry parameter never gets populated with the actual value of id.

```
int id = 1; // <- insert your value here.
string s = String.Format("select id,name from tbl where id={0}", id);
//cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", 1);  <-- remove this line
```

Comment: are you sure? check the post carefully .. it's already present.

Comment: neglected to see this, you are correct.  Yes, the error is he is opening up the connection way too early, before all the properties have been defined.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the comments I added to your code.

I really do understand what your trying to do.  You are trying to parametrize the tsql statement that your sending to the Stored Procedure, and then parametrize the stored procedure.  Unfortunately, you cannot do that.  (You can parametrize a TSQL statement.  You cannot Parameterize a Parameter.)

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycon"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
string s = "select id,name from tbl where id=@id";
con.Open();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = s;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1);  // You set the param here
cmd= new SqlCommand();  // You just effectively erased the previous 4 lines of code with this line.
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "SroredProc";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qry", s);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: I really do understand what your trying to do.  You are trying to parametrize the tsql statement that your sending to the Stored Procedure, and then parametrize the stored procedure.  Unfortunately, you cannot do that.  (You can parametrize a TSQL statement.  You cannot Parameterize a Parameter.)

Comment: In that case anything else that can prevent sql injection ? any help would be appreciated

Comment: In my opinion I would change the design.

Comment: What does that mean will u please elaborate it ?

Comment: Is your objective to set No Count On everytime?  I would just add No Count On on the query, and don't use the stored procedure.  I have a feeling that the only reason you are utilizing this stored procedure is because you read somewhere that Stored Procedures help towards SQL Injection.  Which is true, but it's not applicable for this use.  Get rid of the stored procedure and parametrize your TSQL statement that you have in 'S'.